# Use a recursive dop in APL

Tags: recursion, operators, documentation, apl, user-defined

In the [tryapl.org](https://www.tryapl.org/) Primer when you select the Del glyph (∇) it shows an example of a Double-Del (∇∇) where a dop (as I understand it, a user defined operator) can reference itself in a recursive fashion:

```
Double-Del Syntax:  dop self-reference

    pow←{                ⍝ power operator: apply ⍵⍵ times
        ⍵⍵=0:⍵           ⍝ ⍵⍵ is 0: finished
        ⍺⍺ ∇∇(⍵⍵-1)⍺⍺ ⍵  ⍝ otherwise: recurse
    }
```

Can someone provide me with some examples of this particular dop in use so I can see how to utilize it? I see that a single `⍺` is not used in the body of this dop, only `⍺⍺`; does that make this a monadic dop?

I have tried a number of different ways to use this operator in an expression after it's defined and can't seem to get anything but errors or instances where it appears the body/text of the dop is in an array as text, alongside what I was trying to pass to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Example usage

```
      incr←{1+⍵}      ⍝ define an increment function
      (incr pow 3) 5  ⍝ apply it 3 times to 5
8
```

#### Lack of single `⍺`

The operator has `⍵⍵` which alone makes it a dyadic operator. The lack of a single `⍺` means that, when given the two required operands, it derives a monadic function.

#### Troubleshooting

When an operator takes an array (as opposed to a function) operand adjacent to an argument, it is crucial to separate the operand from the argument. This can be done in any of three ways:

1. Name the derived function and then apply it:

   ```
   add3←incr pow 3
   add3 5
   ```
2. Parenthesise the derived function:

   ```
   (incr pow 3) 5
   ```
3. Separate the operand from the argument using a function (often, the identity function `⊢` is used):

   ```
   incr pow 3 ⊢ 5
   ```

Failing this, the intended operand and argument will strand to a single array, which then becomes the operand, leaving the derived function with no argument that it can apply to:

```
incr pow (3 5)
```

The result is therefore the derived function; the text source you see reported.